# Explicitly define type cast for Generic function in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We have a user defined db function like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(ids integer[],
.
.
```

I call this by sqlalchemy:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
statement = func.my_function(
    [1,2,3,4]
    )
station_count = await db.execute(statement)
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.AmbiguousFunctionError'>: function my_function(unknown) is not unique
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[SQL: SELECT my_function(%s) AS my_function_1]
[parameters: ([1,2,3,4]]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

I think the problem here is about casting the list `[1,2,3,4]` into `integer[]`. But how can I explicitly cast `list[int]` in to `integer[]` while calling the function in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add at least the full function signature if you cannot share the whole function. `CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [ { DEFAULT | = } default_expr ] [, ...] ] ) [ RETURNS rettype | RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] ) ]`

Comment: @ljmc, Thanks for your suggestion. My full function is too big. I thought maybe it's better to just provide it's input.

Comment: @mohammad-eternaddar exactly, if you cannot share the full function please add the signature with arguments and returns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely not with casting a `list[int]` to `integer[]`, it probably has to do with the function name not being unique as the error suggests.

Try examining the existing functions with:

```sql
SELECT routine_name
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_type = 'FUNCTION'
```

Here is an MRE of passing `list[int]` to a function which has a `integer[]` argument.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres", echo=True, future=True)

with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute(
        sa.text(
            """
            CREATE FUNCTION my_sum (ns integer[]) RETURNS integer
            AS $$ SELECT SUM(t) FROM UNNEST(ns) t $$
            LANGUAGE SQL;
            """
        )
    )
    con.commit()

with engine.connect() as con:
    stmt = func.my_sum([1, 2, 3, 4])
    result = con.execute(stmt).scalar_one()

print(result)  # 10
```

---

References:

1. the array sum select is taken from https://cwestblog.com/2012/07/18/postgresql-sum-of-an-array/